# Convert Observable stream to Array

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to convert an observable stream to an array, with my current approach when the count reaches to 5 then I am getting the emitted value as an array.

Is there any way to get an array of the count each time interval emits a value. Like: `[0]`, `[0, 1]`, `[0, 1, 2]` and so on.

```
const interval$ = interval(1000);
    interval$.pipe(
        take(5),
        toArray()
    ).subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
            // Emitting when count reaches to 5
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably are looking for the `scan` operator

```typescript
const interval$ = interval(1000);
interval$
  .pipe(
    scan((prev, next) => [...prev, next], []),
    take(5),
    tap(console.log)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

The above will log

```
[0]
[0,1]
[0,1,2]
[0,1,2,3]
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

See this **[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zvaxta)**

Answer (score 0):

Use the buffercount operator to store emitted values within an array.

```
const interval$ = interval(1000);
    interval$.pipe(
        take(5),
        bufferCount(5)
    ).subscribe({
        next: (data) => {
            // Emitting when count reaches to 5
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```